# Run 12 VDC micro-processor from 480 VAC power supply

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc

I am trying to power a 12VDC (~3 amps) microprocessor module from a 480 VAC grid power. Can I use a 480 VAC to 24VDC (https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/Shopping/Catalog/Power_Products_(Electrical)/DC_Power_Supplies/24VDC,_3-Phase_Input/PSB24-060S-3)

and 24 VDC to 12 VDC 
(http://www.ebay.com/itm/SUPERNIGHT-24Vdc-to-12Vdc-5A-Converter-Step-Down-Regulator-Module-60W-/400611133627)

for proper functioning?

Answer (score 2):

P=UI law gives 3*12=36W under 12V.

Now you need to account for efficiency loss of your 24V - 12V converter which is 90% efficient (10% loss), the power consumption on the 24V will be 40W.

The PSB24-060S-3 module is capable of 60W which is plenty enough for your application.

The answer is YES, it will work; but...

As much as the 24V power supply seems robust, I don't think the 12V is worth trusting when I read that...

> If the ambient temperature exceeds 45 ℃ , please reduce the power output,Or enhance heat dissipation

Your call